# Wordpress cannot create directory on theme install

Tags: wordpress, ftp, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

Brand new site. latest version. All glossy and etc.

I went to add a theme. It asked me for my FTP login details. I added these, but now it just keeps falling over and saying:

`Could not create directory`

Where to from here?

Comment: It's very hard to guess from your question, is there an error code? what FTP client are you using? I suggest you contact your host provider first

Comment: I am the webhost. I'm talking inside of wordpress, not a separate ftp client

Comment: Sorry, should have put, Ubuntu 14.04 server running in AWS cloud. ISPConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: ISPConfig3 does not work on Amazon Web Services because every user needs access to the instance, and adding them is a manual process :(

Swapping to Plesk.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your wp-config.php file, so it will not ask for FTP again.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

If it does not work there are alot of solutions [here](https://www.narga.net/stop-fix-wordpress-ask-for-ftp-credentials-upgrade-install-delete-themes-plugins/)

After that make sure your theme directory has the right permission you can read more about permission here: [codex wordpress file permission](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

If you are not sure about permission, change wordpress, wp-content, wp-includes, wp-admin, plugins and themes to 755 and then install your theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, that has not worked either. I can not get it to proceed.

Comment: The issue is, I'm wanting to resell website hosting, and I don't want each client to have this issue!